# C++: Why does cin allow ints for inputs of strings?

Tags: c++, string, cin

I'm working on a school project that requires the verification of a string for the input, and NOTHING ELSE.  However, whenever I pass an int for bug testing (I.E. 0), the program doesn't trigger cin.fail().  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string lastName;
    cin >> lastName;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "INT";
    }
    else {
        cout << "STRING";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT:
1999

OUTPUT:
STRING

Why is this the case?  I created a personal project using this exact same same structure and had no problems there but can't get it to work properly here.

Comment: The character `0` can be interpreted as a perfectly valid string (`"0"`). It's only a matter of interpretation of the input characters (from cin) that determines the type (int or string etc.).

Comment: Input doesn't have types; it's simply a sequence of characters. When you read characters into a string they get copied into the string. When you use an extractor to read into an `int` the extractor translates the characters into a numeric value.

Comment: Considering that [3M](https://www.3m.com/) is a perfectly fine company name, why would you not allow digits in names?

Comment: ```int 0``` is just ```0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00``` which is a string of bytes, also known as "text" or a "string".  So if ```cin``` expects a byte string and you hand it ```0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00``` it will treat it like a byte string.  Remember, all types are a string of bytes, it's how those byte strings are interpreted which matters.  ```cin``` interprets incoming bytes as "text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is a sequence of characters. Therefore, `1999` is a valid string.

If you want to verify that the string consists only of alphabetical characters and does not contain any digits, you can use the function [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) on every single character in the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string lastName;

    std::cin >> lastName;

    if ( std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Input failure!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    for ( char c : lastName )
    {
        if ( !std::isalpha( static_cast<unsigned char>(c) ) )
        {
            std::cout << "String is invalid!\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "String is valid!\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that in the default [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale), `std::isalpha` will only consider the standard letters `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'a'` to `'z'` as valid letters, but not letters such as `ê` and `ä`. Therefore, you may have to change the locale if you are dealing with non-English characters.

Answer (score -1):

`int 0` is just `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00` which is a string of bytes.  All types are a string of bytes.  It's how those bytes are interpreted that matters.  So if `cin` expects a byte string and you hand it `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00` it will treat it like text.

Inversely, `"jump"` is `0x6a 0x75 0x6d 0x70` which interpreted as a 4-byte integer `int` is `1786080624`.